# Finding Support vectors from a dataset that are the hardest to classify

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to train an svm classifier on an MNIST dataset to distinguish between two characters. I am using an exponential kernel with C=10 and gamma=10^-6. I have also printed the support vectors:

```
clfretrainC=svm.SVC(C=Cfinal,kernel="rbf",gamma=gammafinal)
clfretrainC.fit(ReTraintotx,ReTraintoty)
Pefinal=1-clfretrainC.score(Testtotx,Testtoty)
print "Test Error"
print Pefinal

print "Number of Support Vectors"
print clfretrainC.support_vectors_
print clfretrainC.support_vectors_.shape

sv=clfretrainC.support_vectors_
```

However, I wish to find the support vectors that are the closest to the separating hyperplane and hence the hardest to classify. Is there a function that allows me to do this?

If not, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documenation for sklearn.svm.SVC you'll see:

> decision_function(X)   Distance of the samples X to the separating hyperplane.

So you can just do (for the n closest vectors)

`clf.support_vectors_[np.abs(clf.decision_function(clf.support_vectors_)).argsort()[:n]]`